# Is "befriedet" correctly translated to "pacified" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english, legal-terminology

This is prompted by a question over at [LawSE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67390/what-are-the-laws-for-trespassing-in-germany). In my attempt to answer, I've had to use Google Translate for [this](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__123.html) piece of legislation:

> (1) Wer in die Wohnung, in die Geschäftsräume oder in das befriedete Besitztum eines anderen oder in abgeschlossene Räume, welche zum öffentlichen Dienst oder Verkehr bestimmt sind, widerrechtlich eindringt, oder wer, wenn er ohne Befugnis darin verweilt, auf die Aufforderung des Berechtigten sich nicht entfernt, wird mit Freiheitsstrafe bis zu einem Jahr oder mit Geldstrafe bestraft.

Google gave me this:

> (1) Anyone who illegally intrudes into the apartment, business premises or **pacified** property of another or into locked rooms which are intended for public service or traffic, or who, if he lingers in them without authorization, at the request of the person entitled does not move away, is punished with imprisonment for up to one year or with a fine.

I'm unfamiliar with the concept of a *pacified* property. Is it anyone able to provide an English synonym or some context for me, please?

Comment: Not "pacified", use "enclosed".

Comment: Note that Google Translate does not understand text. Instead, it works very much like a search engine (no surprise there): it tries to find the same text fragments in multiple languages and then matches fragments between them. This works well for contexts where texts about the same subject are available in multiple languages, but German Criminal Law is apparently not one of those. Google Translate routinely fails where terms have a very specialized meaning in a very narrow context that deviates significantly from the common meaning. Legalese happens to be full of those.

Comment: I am a native speaker, and I am also not a computer, and yet I wouldn't have had the slightest idea what that word means without looking up the definition.

Comment: https://www.deepl.com often avoids pitfalls such as this that Google translate falls into

Comment: The best thing would be to look for professional translations in the first place before relying on DeepL etc., let alone Google Translate. The German Federal Ministry of Justice offers a [list](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/Teilliste_translations.html) of non-authorative, but scientifically founded English translations of German federal laws. There we can also find a sound [translation of § 123 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1265): "Whoever unlawfully enters the private premises, business premises or other **enclosed property** of another […]"

Comment: @amadeusamadeus You actually found a semi-official translation of the very text OP was looking for. You should have made your comment an answer, and OP should accept it.

Comment: @StijndeWitt Thanks for the approval. My answer's already there, one has to scroll down a bit to see it. The comment is supposed to show how the use of Google Translate caused the confusion in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The google translation got it wrong, this is not about conquest. In this case "befriedet" = "under legal protection".

https://www.dwds.de/wb/befriedet

This is a slight case of officialese, meaning the property is legally owned by somebody and refers to their right of ownership and to execute some authority, e.g. deny access.

Edit: @guidot remarked that there are more shortcomings of the google translation, with which I agree.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127249/discussion-on-answer-by-a-donda-is-befriedet-correctly-translated-to-pacified).

Comment: The German Federal Ministry of Justice itself [translates](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/Teilliste_translations.html) the term *befriedetes Besitztum* in [§ 123 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1265) as *enclosed property* (i.e. factually enclosed, e.g. by a fence), not as *property under* legal *protection* (which would only be ideally and maybe even tautological).

Comment: @amadeusamadeus That BmJ translation is wrong. I can certainly ask people to leave my grounds if I have not raised a fence or put up "dont enter" signs. If they don't go, that's "Hausfriedensbruch". The correct translation for "enclosed" is "umfriedet".

Comment: @Karl In my opinion that is off-topic, but if you think that it affects the question: no, it is not (!) *Hausfriedensbruch* if someone doesn't leave your ground unless it is *befriedet=umfriedet=eingefriedet* (these are synonyms). Therefor it doesn't even suffice to put up *do-not-enter* signs only, there ought to be a physical barrier. Otherwise the element *befriedet* in the law would be pointless. See [nulla poena sine lege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nulla_poena_sine_lege). You may still have a civil claim, but it's not an offense—and this is why this answer is misleading.

Comment: This is drfiting into opinionated piffle and cantankerousness. Let's leave explaining the law to the lawyers and focus on language use. When I searched for published jurisdiction (just superficially) on the matter I found out that it is not as clear and dogmatic as people here put it and interpreted from case to case, which makes amadeus' apodictic answer wrong. The question has been answered with actually too much information now, so let's move on.

Comment: Tagging @jonathan.scholbach may I ask and would it be possible to move or append this to the chat ? It clutters the whole thread and isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: @a_donda Actually, your answer is an opinion on what *befriedetes Besitztum* means, but it's counterfactual and misleads people. The question is explicitly about the "concept" of *befriedetes Besitztum* in and only in § 123 StGB (it could as well have the tags *meaning-in-context* and *technical-terminology*). This question cannot be correctly answered without relying on the juridical terminology **only**. And the juridical definition is entirely clear: *befriedet* means *having a physical barrier around*. I really don't know why you insist on a not applicable definition despite the arguments

Comment: Unfortunately, these comments cannot be moved again to chat by moderators - due to a consraint of Stackexchange. People, please discuss the legal stuff in chat. It is off-topic and I am inclined to delete all this comments here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach how is a discussion about the meaning of a legal term off topic if the question was what the term means. You cannot translate a legal term correctly if you don't know what it means. The discussion is very much on topic. It's a discussion whether the answer is correct or not. If I downvote the answer, stack exchange itself tells me to leave a comment.

Comment: @DonQuiKong The question stated is whether _befriedet_ can be translated as "pacified" in the given context. This question can be answered without answering the legal subtleties this discussion is about. The discussions in the comments is a discussion for legal scholar's, but it is discussed by legal lay(wo)men in a linguistic forum. For this question, it is off-topic.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach The question continues as follows: "I'm unfamiliar with the concept of a pacified property. Is it anyone able to provide an **English synonym** or some **context** for me, please?" Since *befriedetes Besitztum* is a technical term (*terminus technicus*), that further question cannot be answered by a general meaning of *befriedet*. We need no juridical interpretation, that's right -- on this site it's just about semantics. But to get the semantics right, we need to respect the legal meaning. Otherwise the answer is semantically/pragmatically wrong.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I see discussions of technical subtleties of jargon words to be out of scope for this site. And the discussion here reflects that: Nobody here really knows what they are talking about, as soon as it comes to legal subtleties.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus This meta discussion belongs to meta. That is why I opened a thread there: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/how-to-deal-with-legal-questions/1641 Please, let us discuss the meta question there.

Answer (score 25):

„Befriedetes Besitztum“ has an additional special meaning in legalese. It is "a property or building that is secured against unauthorized entry in a recognizable manner by contiguous protective barriers by the authorized person." (Oberlandesgericht Frankfurt 2006) *(...ein Grundstück bzw. Gebäude, „das von dem Berechtigten in äußerlich erkennbarer Weise durch zusammenhängende Schutzwehren gegen das beliebige Betreten gesichert ist“)*

This means that a property must be fenced in ("umfriedet"). Putting up warning signs saying "private property" or the like is not enough to constitute "befriedetes Besitztum".

https://www.rv.hessenrecht.hessen.de/bshe/document/LARE190012602 (Grund 14)

Comment: +1 Wußte ich nicht. Wahrscheinlich hat mich der Bauer als Bub zu oft vom Acker gejagt. Jetzt müßte man noch wissen wie militärisch die "zusammenhängenden Schutzwehren" denn ausgeführt sein müssen. Ich liebe amtsdeutsch :-)

Comment: @a_donda: Ich kannte es auch nur vom Schießen mit Pfeil und Bogen oder Luftgewehr. Das ist aus naheliegenden Gründen nämlich auch nur auf befriedetem Besitztum erlaubt.

Comment: Es gibt auch den Begriff "Einfriedung" - Das ist i.A. ganz profan ein Zaun oder eine Mauer drumrum. Ich finde allerdings "befriedet" hier im Gesetzestext ein bißchen befremdlich. Aber das ist wohl gemeint.

Comment: I would go for "enclosed", which is contains all the meanings of fenced, walled, etc.

Comment: This BTW is why we have a _Friedhof_. Not because there's so much peace in there.

Comment: Nitpicking, but that's unclear. https://www.dwds.de/wb/Friedhof. Burial practice and places and their construction or the lack thereof change. 'Burgfried' (not 'Burgfriede') is a better example imo.

Comment: @tofro *Ich finde allerdings "befriedet" hier im Gesetzestext ein bißchen befremdlich*: Well, the wording is older than 1872, back then it seemed probably less strange. Nowadays it wouldn't be wise to change it since it has become a technical term. The GDR (DDR), however, used [*umschlossenes Grundstück*](http://www.verfassungen.de/ddr/strafgesetzbuch74.htm) instead.

Answer (score 11):

> Is "befriedet" correctly translated to "pacified" here?

The word "*befriedet*" does not come from the word "*Friede*" but from the word "*Einfriedung*".

A "*Einfriedung*" is any kind of structure that marks the border of some area not allowing people to enter - for example a fence, a wall or a hedge.

So the expression "*befriedetes Besitztum*" in this sentence means: "An area which is surrounded by a structure like a fence or a wall."

Comment: … but “Einfriedung” in turn comes from the same word as “Frieden”. The homonym meaning of “befrieden” being “pacify” isn’t a coincidence.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: I think the question is best answered by the [semi-official English translation](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/Teilliste_translations.html), offered by the *Bundesministerium der Justiz* (German Federal Ministry of Justice):

> [Section 123](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p1265)
> Trespass
>
> (1) Whoever unlawfully enters the private premises, business premises or other **enclosed property** of another, or closed premises designated for public service or transportation, or whoever stays there without being authorised to do so and does not leave when requested to do so by the authorised person incurs a penalty of imprisonment for a term not exceeding one year or a fine.
>
> […]

---

Given the debate regarding one definition, I would like to take the history of the law in question into account and give more linguistic and legislative sources.

The term *befriedet* has been in § 123 Abs. 1 StGB since the [very first version of the StGB from 1872](https://lexetius.com/StGB/123,5). In the [DWB entry](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/befrieden) that was published in 1853 – only 19 years prior –, we read:

> BEFRIEDEN, protegere […], wurde zumal auf das hegen und schirmen des landes und feldes gegen feinde und schädiger angewandt […]

In English:

> *BEFRIEDEN*, protegere […], was especially applied to fostering and sheltering the ground and field against enemies and wrongdoers […]

Accordingly, *befriedet* in the sense of § 123 Abs. 1 StGB must be understood as an estate that is somehow delimited and protected from trespassing, that can be by a wall, by a fence etc. – maybe *enclosed* would be an appropriate English term.

At the time of legislation, *befrieden* was probably more an everyday language term than a *terminus technicus*/legal term. The more recent legal definitions, e.g. by the German Federal Court, that were cited by other answers and comments are a specification of that 'natural' meaning, but they didn't re-invent it. First of all, *befrieden* meant *to protect a piece of land*. In the context of the formation of the trespassing law in the German penal code of 1872, that must necessesarily mean *by an enclosure*.

§ 134 Abs. 1 of the [penal code of the GDR](http://www.verfassungen.de/ddr/strafgesetzbuch74.htm) used the term *umschlossenes Grundstück* (literally 'enclosed estate') instead which means the same.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Please upvote.